# How Nosql like bigtable stores Image data?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, bigtable, wide-column-store

In the paper of Bigtable, it is represented with A Distributed Storage System for Structured Data.

I'm confused with the terms "structured data".
I know that structured data so formal that the data is easily classified and searched.

How Nosql like Bigtable stores image data?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Bigtable has a binary key and binary values.  (It also has families and qualifiers, but that's not too important for this question).  There's also a 10MB size limit for values.  If you have small images, then you can put the image in the Cell value.  You can put other classification data in other cell values.